# How to replace certain value of column in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace certain value in a column with ' ' but it is replacing all the values.
Can you please tell me what am doing wrong?

Example:

df:

```
  output_condition
0 AND
1 OR
2 THEN 'Unsolicited Question From Field'
3 THEN 'Unsolicited Question Direct'
4 AND
5 AND
6 OR
7 THEN 'Introduction'
```

Expected Output:

df:

```
  output_condition
0 
1 
2 THEN 'Unsolicited Question From Field'
3 THEN 'Unsolicited Question Direct'
4 
5 
6 
7 THEN 'Introduction'
```

I am doing the below code:

```
df['output_condition'] = df['output_condition'].replace('AND', '', inplace=True)
df['output_condition'] = df['output_condition'].replace('OR', '', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions if need replace all `AND` and `OR` also in **subtrings**:

Your code is necessary change for remove assign back, because `inplace` parameter return `None`, also both values are joined by `|` for regex or for `AND` or `OR`:

```
df['output_condition'].replace('AND|OR', '', inplace=True, regex=True)
```

Solution with no `inplace`:

```
df['output_condition'] = df['output_condition'].replace('AND|OR', '', regex=True)
print (df)
                         output_condition
0                                        
1                                        
2  THEN 'Unsolicited Question From Field'
3      THEN 'Unsolicited Question Direct'
4                                        
5                                        
6                                        
7                     THEN 'Introduction'
```

I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

---

If need replace non substrings values use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
vals = ['AND','OR']
df['output_condition'] = df['output_condition'].mask(df['output_condition'].isin(vals), '')
print (df)
                         output_condition
0                                        
1                                        
2  THEN 'Unsolicited Question From Field'
3      THEN 'Unsolicited Question Direct'
4                                        
5                                        
6                                        
7                     THEN 'Introduction'
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['output_condition'].isin(vals))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
Name: output_condition, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Since `'AND|OR'` is regex, you may need to add `regex=True`. But then that's not really what OP needs.

Comment: @QuangHoang - hmmm, why do you think so?

Comment: I think OP wants to replace the whole value. For example `AND` in `THEN 'Unsolicited AND Question'` would not get replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop `inplace=True`:

```
df['output_condition'] = df['output_condition'].replace('AND', '')
df['output_condition'] = df['output_condition'].replace('OR', '')
```

Or you can chain:

```
df['output_condition'] = df['output_condition'].replace('AND', '').replace('OR', '')
```

However, since you are replacing the whole value, you can use `isin()`:

```
 df.loc[df['output_condition'].isin(['AND','OR']), 'output_condition'] = ''
```

Output:

```
                         output_condition
0                                        
1                                        
2  THEN 'Unsolicited Question From Field'
3      THEN 'Unsolicited Question Direct'
4                                        
5                                        
6                                        
7                     THEN 'Introduction'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work too:

```
df['output_condition'].apply(lambda x: '' if x=='AND' or 'OR' else x)
```